# Why can't I use a variable in the selector of the .querySelector function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jquery-selectors, puppeteer

```
let x = 1;
let y = 'div[class = "log-viewer"] > p:nth-child(' + x.toString() + ')';
let var1 = document.querySelector(y);
```

When I do this, var1 = null. This confuses me because if I typed out the string contained in *y* into the .querySelector function, I receive the appropriate output. Does anyone know why this is? My final goal is to be able to put querySelector in a loop so I can put every child into an array.

Comment: Could you provide an example of the HTML code that such a query should match?

Comment: This would work. If it doesn't, it's not because of the selector - something else is wrong.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your quick reply. Here you go: <span class="at">01:51</span>&nbsp;"TQ @ aYdtgLqIEQ" raises with 300

Comment: I got this by using document.querySelector('div[class = "log-viewer"] > p:nth-child(1)').innerHTML;

Answer (score 0):

I think something might be wrong with the query and the page.

If you click on the blue button to run the code snippet you'll see that your code works

```js
let x = 1;
let y = 'div[class = "log-viewer"] > p:nth-child(' + x.toString() + ')';
let var1 = document.querySelector(y);
console.log('here is the value', var1 && var1.innerText)
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="log-viewer">
  <p>p1</p>
  <p>p2</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to do this. My code now works (I'm not exactly sure what I did, but it's consistently working now). The error message I was getting didn't actually have to do with the querySelector function - another part of my code was timing out when I used query.Selector(y) rather than the literal selector. I'm not sure what changed so that it's no longer timing out - but I've run it multiple times now and it's working consistently.

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness, this is my first personal coding project and I'm still learning the ropes